Tailwind class is getting added but style is not applied in nextjs
I am trying to create a board game which includes keeping track of players that who is on which square. So if player is currently on currently rendering block I want to show a small dot of a particular color.
Here is my template code
<div className="board">
  {board.map((val, idx) => {
    return (
      <div className="row" key={idx}>
        {val.map((block) => {
          return (
            <div className="block" key={block!.index}>
              {block!.index}
              <div className="player-dots">
                {players.map((player: PlayerType) => {
                  if (player.currentSquare === block!.index) {
                    let colorClass: string = `bg-player${player.id}color`;
                    return (
                      <div
                        className={`h-3 w-3 rounded-full ${colorClass}`}
                        key={player.id}
                      ></div>
                    );
                  }
                })}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>;

And the tailwind config is
const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
    },
    colors: {
      midnight: "#121063",
      primary: "#3A0CA3",
      secondary: "#4361EE",
      tertiary: "#4CC9F0",
      rose: "#F72585",
      grape: "#7209B7",
      white: "#ffffff",
      player1color: "#FF0000",
      player2color: "#0FA3B1",
      player3color: "#E072A4",
      player4color: "#3D3B8E",
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/forms")],
};
export default config;

In the DOM we can see that the class is getting added but style is not applied

I tried generating class name dynamically within className but that also did not work.

You cannot construct dynamic classnames with Tailwind, see https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names.
Either include all variants in full without a string template or include the classes that are not generated in your tailwind config safeList:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
  safelist: [
    'bg-player1color',
    'bg-player2color',
  ]
  // ...
}


So, the problem you're facing here is due to the dynamic class you're creating. TailwindCSS does not support dynamic class because it only renders the classes that are present in your code when compiling your CSS.
Solution 1: The best solution would be to create your own CSS file and style the players according to your preferences.
Solution 2: Another thing you may consider is to create a hidden div and put all the TailwindCSS classes you need inside.
<div class="hidden bg-player1color"></div>

I do not recommend using the second solution but it works.
